# Unable to see next/previous arrows in jQuery Liquid Carousel plugin

Tags: jquery, carousel

Hello,

I am developing a `jquery carousel` based on [jQuery Liquid Carousel plugin](http://www.nikolakis.net/liquidcarousel/) but I'm unable to see the next and previous arrows - why is this?

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/g8FaN/

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.nikolakis.net/liquidcarousel/css/liquidcarousel.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.nikolakis.net/liquidcarousel/js/jquery.liquidcarousel.pack.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#liquid').liquidcarousel({ height: 129, duration: 100, hidearrows: false });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style ="width:200px">
        <div id="liquid">
            <span class="previous"></span>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif" width="88" height="126" alt="image" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif" width="88" height="126" alt="image" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif" width="88" height="126" alt="image" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif" width="88" height="126" alt="image" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif" width="88" height="126" alt="image" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif" width="88" height="126" alt="image" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif" width="88" height="126" alt="image" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif" width="88" height="126" alt="image" /></a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif" width="88" height="126" alt="image" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif" width="88" height="126" alt="image" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif" width="88" height="126" alt="image" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif" width="88" height="126" alt="image" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <span class="next"></span>
        </div>
    </div style ="width:200px">
</body>
```

What did I do wrong here, because I'm unable to see next and previous button? Can anybody look into it?

Answer (score 0):

Change `<div id="liquid">` to `<div class="liquid">` for the div holding your images.

then change your jquery code to `$('.liquid')...`

Here you can see it in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g8FaN/1/

Comment: i dont think so. From what i saw on the liquidcarousel site, I believe its supposed to add the class to the element. But it wasn't. So i took a look at the css and noticed that the arrows were being referenced to `.liquid .next` and `.liquid .previous`. So changing it to class worked.

Comment: ok, but i got another issue, if i made image width and height 60x 70, the distance between them became so large!

Comment: could you provide me another jsfiddle please?

Answer (score -1):

Open liquidcarousel.css and search for this class

```
.liquid ul li {
    width:126px;
    padding:0 2px;
    margin:0;
}
```

and remove the width property

```
.liquid ul li {
    padding:0 2px;
    margin:0;
}
```

always set the height of your image and let the width be dynamic according to height.
Sure it works.